# jquery selector

Tags: jquery

Hi
this is my html code :

```
<ul>
    <li>li 1</li>
    <li>li 2</li>
    <li>li 3</li>
    <li>li 4</li>
    <li>li 5</li>
</ul>
```

and this is my jquery code :

```
$('ul li').each(function(index)
{
    if( index > 2 )
    {
        $(this).css('color','red');
    }
});
```

and this is jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/YLBcs/

i want to know that exist a other way to do this work without each function ?

Comment: What if there are multiple `<ul>`s?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for the [`:gt` selector](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/):

```
$('ul li:gt(2)').css('color','red');
```

Comment: @Davood take a look on answe on mine

Answer (score 2):

```
$('ul li').slice(3).css('color','red');
```

Answer (score 1):

SLaks answer quite better. try this one. it's perform faster then SLaks example

```
$('li:gt(2)','ul').css('color','blue');
```